# How to implement "sort by" and "filter by" of items?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sorting

I am new to iOS development. I am developing a small e-commence application and I want to know how to implement "sort by" and "filter by" of items(clothes/bags/shoes etc).That means when I click on "sort by" button it should show the options as sort by Popularity, Price:High to low and low to high and New arrival and also  whenever I click on one of these options it should filter out the items/data as desired. Little help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What are you sorting? Where is it stored? Is it just an array of items? Is it stored in CoreData? Is it something you're downloading from a server? How are you displaying the items? Is it in a tableview? We'll need a lot more information about what it is you're doing before we will be able to help :)

Comment: Data/images is on the web server.But, before fetch and load data from web server I want to implement these two buttons.So I am using array of items. I have stored some temporary images in my project. And I have created an UICollectionView to display number of images(e.g. to show mens wear items etc.) I want to sort these images/items. Some example code/reference link will be helpful. first of all I just want to add and show these sorting names(Popularity, Price, New arrival) to the sort by button. I am stuck at here.

Comment: What is the structure of your data? Paste some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort and filter your list of items using NSSortDescriptor and NSPredicate apply to your array to get resulted array. I am giving here example to show it.

```
@interface Person : NSObject{
NSNumber *age,
NSString *name,
}
```

Here I am sorting based on age

```
NSArray *listArray = @[person1, person2, person3....];

NSSortDescriptor*sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"age" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedListArray = [listArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

And to filter items from your existing array , you can use predicate to find it.
lets say I have to filter for those person, their age is greater than 20 years.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Age>=20"]
filteredArray =  [listArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: great job, this works for me... :)